# Serialization error when setter of public property assigns "value" to a collection

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I understand that this is causing the error, but I don't understand why and how to get around it. I'm looking for a way to avoid having to create hundreds of variables

- is1_BufferUAbsolute
- is2_BufferUAbsolute
- ...
- is75_BufferUAbsolute

by replacing it with

initialStopCollection[n].BufferUAbsolute

[Serialization Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUtDI.png)

Comment: You should be ensuring the value is not null before assigning and have you ensured that the collection index has been initialised ? ie. generally if you've never had an item in the 5th collection slot before it will not allow you to insert something into the 5th slot until its been initialised, ie. with Collection.Add(), but it depends on the type of collection. What type of collection are you dealing with and what type of values are you trying to assign to it? Can you provide more info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should be changed to:

```
set
{
    int itemIndex = 1;
    if (initialStopCollection == null) initialStopCollection = new ...; // your initialStopCollection is null. Create new one
    if (itemIndex >= initialStopCollection.Count) // Two few items, create new
    {
        for (int i = initialStopCollection.Count; i <= itemIndex; i++)
        {
            initialStopCollection.Add(new ...);
        }
    }
    if (initialStopCollection[itemIndex] == null) initialStopCollection[itemIndex] = new ... ; // This item is not initialized, create new
    initialStopCollection[itemIndex].BufferUAbsolute = value;
}
```